# Average 3 rows that contain mm:hh:ss

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

In my table I have 3 colmuns

```
T1      T2      T3
```

I want to average the time in all 3.

My query in design view is set as follows:

```
Score: Avg([swim]+[bike]+[run])
```

In total, I have it done as an expression.

When I run the query an example result shows as: `8.81406810035843E-02`

Any ideas how I can get it to show the average time over all 3 correctly?

I have also changed the format to `hh:nn:ss` - The results looks better but not correct

Comment: Do you want the average for each record separately? Or the total average over all records?

Comment: Hi Andre - The average of all 3

Comment: Please read my question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are looking for this

```
Score: Avg(([swim]+[bike]+[run])/3)
```

Using the `Avg()` funciton, you are making average of every time in column. Adding them together, the resulting time is too huge to show for access. When you average something in one row, you have to add it up and then divide by number of each member.